# Getting equal space around the paragraph with higher line-height is possible?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the space around became `10px`. but i required to use the line height as double here. I am not getting the space around as equal. what would be the correct approach to get? I am getting it on left and right. But not top and bottom.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

div{
  background:yellow;
  padding:10px;
}

div p {
  line-height: 2;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove half a `line-height` from the padding top and bottom

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

div{
  background:yellow;
  padding:calc(10px - 0.5em) 10px;
  margin:5px;
}

div p {
  line-height: 2em; /* will give the same result as 2 */
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="font-size:20px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="font-size:30px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>
```

With CSS variable to easily control

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

div{
  --l:2em;
  --p:10px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:calc(var(--p) - var(--l)/4) var(--p);
  margin:5px;
}

div p {
  line-height: var(--l);
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="font-size:25px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="--l:3em;--p:20px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="--l:3em;--p:20px;font-size:25px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>
```

To cover all the cases (it's an approximation since the calculation can be more complex)

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

div{
  --l:2em;
  --p:10px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:calc(var(--p) - var(--l)/4) max(var(--p),var(--l)/2);
  margin:5px;
   box-shadow:0 0 0 max(var(--p),var(--l)/2) inset #ff000055; /* to illustrate */
}

div p {
  line-height: var(--l);
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="--l:1em;--p:20px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>

<div style="--l:6em;--p:0px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How does calc work with `px - em`, for example if font size is `16px` wouldn't `calc(10px - 1em)` be `calc(10px - 16px)` resulting in a negative value? Apparently that's not how it works

Comment: @TJ negative values aren't allowed so it will get defaulted to 0 so 10px - 16px will be 0 .. I went a bit fast for this one, it should be /4 not /2. It should be half one line-height but from both side

Comment: This won't work for a larger value like 5em and 10px padding on the sides. Padding also needs to be calculated.

Comment: @TJ well, this out of the question scope but update my answer anyway to cover all the cases

Comment: My answer had already covered the specific case in question. So if you're adding an answer on top of it using `calc` then it needs to actually work with different values right? Otherwise what's the point of calc and variables

Comment: @TJ so say it from the beginning if you think my answer is useless and repeating yours. First: I didn't saw your answer when I was posting mine (I was writing mine when 0 answer were posted), there are 2 min between our answers (I didn't submit mine after 1h). Second: when I saw your answer you didn't explain how you got the 2px, your initial submit contain only the final result when my answer already cover the calculation. Third: My answer is different from yours because I am doing the calculation inside the code and not doing it manually so I am not adding an answer on the top of yours.

Comment: ^ fourth I am adding CSS variables that cover most of the cases and I never claimed I will cover all them since it's out of the question scope

Comment: ^Five: my answer will work even if you change the font-size while yours consider *only* the case of 16px font-size

Answer (score 0):

Say your default font-size is `16px`, `line-height: 2` makes `line-height: 32px`. Space around your `16px` text = 32-16 = `16px`. That means `8px` extra space on top and bottom.
So you only need `2px` padding top and bottom to have a total of `10px` whitespace.

It would be like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

div p {
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores laborum voluptates nobis vero minima corporis, magnam officia asperiores repudiandae at voluptatibus, iste deserunt. Nam, provident architecto? Minus, repellat, veniam!</p>
</div>
```